# Why doesn't html see the js file connected to it?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't html see the js file connected to it? I'm doing everything right, but after my attempts, js does not work completely. Wherever I put `<script src="main.js"></script>`, js stops working. What am I doing wrong?

main.html:

```html
...

<body>
    ...
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script>
        onCheckLogin();

        onCheckRole();

        document.querySelector('#checkLogin').addEventListener('click', onCheckLogin);
        document.querySelector('#posts').addEventListener('click', onDeletePost);
        document.querySelector('#posts').addEventListener('click', onEditPost);
        document.querySelector('#search_button').addEventListener('click', onSearchPosts);
        document.querySelector('#posts').addEventListener('click', onShowPost);

        function onDeletePost(event) {
            ...
        }

        function onEditPost(event) {
            ...
        }

        function onShowPost(event) {
            ...
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

main.js:

```js
function onRenderRubricPosts(value) {
    ...
}

function onSearchPosts() {
    ...
}

function onCheckLogin() {
    ...   
}

function onCheckRole() {
    ...
}
```

Browser console:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: looks like a path issue..

Comment: @RachelGallen, html and js files are in the same folder

Comment: Your console is telling you that the first line of `main.js` contains a `<` character.

Comment: @Rounin, thanks, I can read, but the `main.js` does not contain this symbol at the beginning, as you can see from the code above - the file starts with a function

Comment: I solved the problem. Connecting the js file to the html is correct, the problem was on the server. There were two main.js files.

Comment: Sorry, @Alex - that really wasn't intended to come across so bluntly. I meant to write it only in a matter-of-fact sense, not in a pointed sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you say JS stops working, are you talking about JS outside of the main.js file, or the JS inside the main.js file?

Your page might be breaking down because;

1. You have a path issue.
   Meaning, the HTML page isn't actually including the main.js file and then when you try to access functions from that file, the JavaScript interpreter throws an error.
2. You have a syntax or other error in your Main.js file.
   If JS on the page works fine without main.js but breaks when it is included then you might have an error in your main.js file that is tripping up your interpreter.

In any case, look up how to view the development console of your browser, it should show you what is going on.

If the path to your main.js is incorrect it will show you a 404 error, if there's a fault with your JS then it will kindly tell you what fault and where to find it.

That's all I can say with the current information provided.

Answer (score 0):

hi you may try with add the script with the head of the html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I tried adding the script within the head of the html file and it worked, similar like colleague said.
`<html> <head> <script src="main.js"></script> </head> <body> </body> </html>`